# Opening a Git project in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

It seems I've cloned the project by clicking **Team -> Git -> Clone** and then entering the url and my credentials and clicking next till the end, but the folder in my Netbeans is a sibling folder to the `src` folder I want to be working in.

The folder open in my Netbeans is in `~/project/newProjectFolder` but I want to be working in `~/project/src`.

When I click **File -> Open Project**, I can't click on the `src` folder to open up my project.

What I want is to be able to open this project from git and make some edits to it, within Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans git clone wizard on 3rd screen you can customize where the project will be cloned. If you leave default settings it will create new folder with the name of the repository inside your projects folder.

This is equivalent to:

```
cd ~/project
git clone git@github.com:XXX/newProjectFolder.git
```

Project is inside `newProjectFolder`.

If you select `~/project` as *Parent Directory* and `src` as *Clone Name* you will clone project to `src` folder. This is equivalent to:

```
cd ~/project
git clone git@github.com:XXX/newProjectFolder.git src
```

Project is inside `src`.

If project doesn't contain Netbeans meta folder then you have to create new project with option *... with existing sources* and select `~/project/src`.

[image: netbeans git clone]